# Pass Node.js Buffer to C++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

**test.js**

```
buf = new Buffer(100);
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) buf[i] = i
addon.myFync(buf);
```

**addon.cpp**

```
Handle<Value> set(const Arguments& args) {
    char *buf = SOMETHING(args[0]);
    return Undefined();
}
```

How to get the pointer to a data of the buffer inside the C++ function?

What should I write in place of `SOMETHING(args[0])`?

I have node_buffer.h opened in my editor, but I cannot figure out.

Node version = `v0.10.29`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
char* buf = node::Buffer::Data(args[0]);
```

to directly access the bytes of a `Buffer`.

Comment: Great! I found it also works if you pass typed array, `Uint32Array` for example.

Comment: The fact that it works with `Uint32Array` may just be a coincidence, but I'm not as familiar with that so I can't say much more.

Comment: are node::Buffer:Data() or node::Buffer:Length() null terminated?

Comment: @sgonzalez Seems unlikely but better to post a new question.

Comment: This solution needs an update for the Node Addon API.

Answer (score 0):

According to the node.js [node binding documentation](http://luismreis.github.io/node-bindings-guide/docs/arguments.html) the 'arg[0]' value argument can be accessed as:

```
String::AsciiValue v(args[0]->ToString());
```