# How do I return a Javascript Buffer (i.e an unsigned char *) from C++ to NodeJS in an addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

When I do from a C++ Addon to NodeJS

```
void MyFunction(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
  Isolate       *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  unsigned char *buffer  = "something";
  unsigned int   len     = 9;
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(buffer);
}
```

I get the error:

```
.node-gyp/9.2.0/include/node/v8.h:162:37: 
error: cannot convert ‘v8::Primitive*’ to ‘unsigned char** volatile’ in assignment
```

I've also looked here: [how to deliver c++ array to node.js using v8 native addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851438/how-to-deliver-c-array-to-node-js-using-v8-native-addon) but there is no answer about returning an unsigned char *  ***from C++*** to NodeJS. Instead both examples show how to route buffers from NodeJS into the C++ addon (and convert them to char *)

I would like on 'the other side' in my nodejs to have

```
const buffer = myaddon.myfunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

A node.js buffer is represented as a `node::Buffer` object.
To create one from a byte array, use `node::Buffer::Copy` - for example:

```
Local<node::Buffer> js_buffer =
    node::Buffer::Copy(isolate,
        (const char *)buffer,
        buffer_size)
    .ToLocalChecked();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, this but am getting an error. any ideas?error: template argument 1 is invalid
   Local<node::Buffer> js_buffer = node::Buffer::Copy(isolate,(const char *)binary_buffer
                     ^
../c.cpp:152:110: error: cannot convert ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
 fer = node::Buffer::Copy(isolate,(const char *)buffer,len).ToLocalChecked();